# Where to find tutorials/guides on how to create more advanced operations?

Tags: python, scripting

I am interested in learning more about how to create Blender Plugins. So far I have made basic operations and panels however I am unsure how to make more advanced plugins that execute operations based on user input, like a textbox. Where would I find more information regarding this?

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.htm , https://docs.python.org/3.10/ , also you can find other add-ons in the [add-ons folder](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html) They are .py files so you can read their code for examples. But questions for resources and tutorials are off-topic here.